# Query about the ion tail of a comet

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, astrophysics, astronomy, comets

I understand that the solid gas coating the nucleus of a comet is melted and that this gas is ionised by the UV rays from the sun. This makes the gas particles charged.

What I dont understand is why they are always pointing away from the sun. I agree that they would be affected by magnetic fields, however I dont see why this means they follow a path away from the sun. Magnetic fields provide a force perpendicular to the direction of motion, not a long it. I've seen several explanations on other websites where they give a vague description as the gas is being carried by the solar winds along the suns magentic field lines, but I dont understand how this is possible.

Can someone please clarify why the ion tail of a comet always points away from the sun?

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_tail#Magnetosphere) discusses this. Also see the linked general article on magnetospheres.

Comment: What's your objection to *the gas is being carried by the solar winds along the suns magentic field lines*? Relatively speaking, there's a lot of kinetic & magnetic energy in the solar wind, particularly close to the sun. True, it's not very dense, but neither is the gas in a comet's tail.

Comment: My objection is that unlike an electric field, the force applied by a magnetic field on charges is not along the field lines. The charges would have a force applied to them that is perpendicular to the direction of the field. So I don't understand how they move along the field lines if they are always receiving a force perpendicular to them.

Comment: Ah, ok. The charged particles can move along the magnetic field lines in a helical trajectory. http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_29.html

Comment: That makes sense, but is it actually observed? In all the pictures Ive seen it looks like a straight tail, is that only because of the limited resolution? Just wondering why we don't see helical tails.

Comment: The curvature of the helices is pretty tight. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/311847/123208